# Can't select data of Kendo Multiselect using Tab key press

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am able to select Data listed into [Kendo Multiselect](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index) by pressing 'Enter' button or by selecting it using 'Mouse click'. But can't select it by pressing 'TAB' key

Answer (score 0):

You can select Value in multiselect on pressing 'TAB' key using HTML helper provided by kendo as `.HighlightFirst(true)`

that you can implement with your Kendo Autocomplete as:

```
                    @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                          .Name("User")
                          .DataTextField("UserName")
                          .Filter("contains")
                          .HighlightFirst(true)
                          .MinLength(2)
                          .DataSource(source =>
                          {
                              source.Read(read =>
                              {
                                  read.Action("GetUsers", "GetData");
                              }).ServerFiltering(true);
                          })
                    )
```

This will select First Value in Autocomplete and you can choose & press `TAB key` for selection of result.